# Routing to a web app slot with query parameters

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-appservice, azure-deployment-slots

I have created a web app with multiple slots in azure, I can use it for my A|B testing.

Lets say `https://mysite.azurewebsites.net` is my production site
`https://mysite-staging.azurewebsites.net` is my staging site.

When I enable the traffic route (say 30%) to staging slot, whenever user user hits the production url with query parameters - `https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/?name=xyz&id=1`, it is routing that request to staging slot without query parameters `https://mysite-staging.azurewebsites.net`.

How can we route the request without dropping any query params?